# Unity Object Collision occurring without objects colliding

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, collider

In my game my player avoid the obstacles and move towards the goal, but when i play the game in device its started colliding the game.

I tried to collide in editor but its not the issue anymore. here is the picture for detail info alt text

[image: Check this image for more info]

this is my player passing aside of an obstacle but in device its triggered the collision but its not colliding with the object.

What could be the issue, i really have no idea what's going on..

I am using OnCollision2D to check the collision.

Edit: Here is Rigidbody2D inspector

[image: rigidbody inspector]

Comment: add screenshots of rigidbody component's inspector as well

Comment: @UmairM updated the question

Comment: which object is it attached to? And post the OnCollision2D code as well

Comment: Why not find out which GameObject it is colliding with? That can help determine why?
`void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        Debug.Log(coll.gameObject.name);
    }`